# Java Jax-rs - get only file body in payload - remove headers

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have to upload a binary file to my server using UI/Postman client. My backend code for Rest API is:

```
    @POST
    @Produces({JSONHeaders.MEDIA_TYPE_JSONAPI, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("loadLicense")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response loadLicense2(@ApiParam("load a license") File input) {
        ....
    }
```

But the file I get has header details added to it which I don't need. File content is something like:

```
----------------------------013134317098674079511595^M
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="license.lic"^M
Content-Type: application/octet-stream^M
^M
^@^@^T.^@^@m.....^@^@^@^K^@^A^@^@^@^@^C^@^@^@(^@.^E^@^@^@^K^@.^@^@^@^G.^@^@^@^K^@.^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^K^@.^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^K^@.^@^@^@^@^F^@^@^@^K^@.^@^@^
^@^@^@^U^@^N^BGR^@^@^@^@^M^@^G^Bc^@^@^@^@^K^@^O^B1.0^@^@^@^@^Q^@4^Bpermanent^@^@^@^@^G^@.
^G.^V......I..^HC_.^^.^U...Y..G.^K.R.^?^O&..^.{V.Z.......h^B.<^O....w'#bk.^B]..*...8.W93...Z.\.....     ..g.a+.....,^M
----------------------------013134317098674079511595--^M
```

But I just need the binary content. Is there any way to do that?

**Note**: I tried @FormParam - it doesn't work and I get this error
`The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded]`

Tried @FormDataParam - not able to resolve it in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `@FormParam` you might need to use `@FormDataParam`, depending on how you send the data via Postman. They have different purposes, i.e. are for use with different MIME types:

- `@FormParam` is intended to be used with MIME type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (constant `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`)
- `@FormDataParam` is intended to be used with `multipart/form-data` (constant `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`)

The following snippet expects the file being sent via form data:

```
    @POST
    @Produces({JSONHeaders.MEDIA_TYPE_JSONAPI, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("loadLicense")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response loadLicense2(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream istream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition disp) {
    }
```

The input stream contains the binary data, the second parameter gives you some information about the uploaded file, e.g. the file name.

You need the `jersey-media-multipart` artifact for this:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I am not able to resolve @FormDataParam even after adding maven dependency.

Comment: I made a mistake - version should be `3.0.2`, not `3.02`. Edited my answer accordingly.